# Spring MVC: Model from URL Parameters

Tags: java, spring-mvc

Suppose I have a model like this:

```
@Setter
public class FooClass {
    private String a;
    private String b;
}
```

And an Endpoint like this where I instantiate an Instance of FooClass like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/myendpoint")
public ModelAndView myEndpoint(HttpServletRequest req) {
    FooClass foo = new FooClass();
    foo.setA(req.getAttribute("a");
    footSetB(req.getAttribute("b");
    
    // stuff
}
```

This endpoint receives requests with payload of content-type x-www-form-urlencoded, which is essentially just URL parameters.
So the payload can look like this:

```
?a=Val&b=Val2
```

If I receive a payload as json I canjust @RequestBody and automatically get an instance of FooClass for matching attribute names.

What I want to do is something like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/myendpoint")
public ModelAndView myEndpoint(@ModelAttribute("foo") FooClass myFoo, BindingResult error, RHttpServletRequest req) {
    FooClass foo = new FooClass();
    foo.setA(req.getAttribute("a");
    footSetB(req.getAttribute("b");
    
    // stuff
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: You're looking for `@RequestParam`, I think, but `@ModelAttribute` may collect enough of what you need all on its own. You haven't described what you've tried that isn't working.

Comment: I've tried using `@ModelAttribute` (maybe I made a mistake) and I tried to use `@RequestBody` just to see if it works.
I'll try out `@RequestParam`, thank you

Comment: It is not usual to need a value for the `@ModelAttribute` annotation; try removing it.